# Add another information to the enum fields

Tags: java, enums

I have the following enum `Group` whick I am unsing to return the right id String depends on the parameter `word2` String.

**Code 1**

```
public enum Group {

    KG1("10460"),
    KG2("10461"),
    KG3("10462"),
    KG4("10463");

    private Group (String id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    private final String id;

    public String getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public static String getGroupByWord2(String word2){
        if(word2.contains("other company")){
            return KG3.toString();
        }else if(word2.contains("neu company")){
            return KG1.toString();
        }

        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getId();
    }

}
```

Now I want to add the information `other company, neu company` to the enum fields. Therefore I changed the enum to this form below but I am facing probem
that it does not deliver the same result as of the `code 1`. How can add the Strings `other company, neu company` to enum fields to deliver the same result as in `code 1`?

**Code 2**

```
public enum Group {

KG1("10460", "neu company"),
KG2("10461", ""),
KG3("10462", "other company"),
KG4("10463", "");

    private Group (String id, String word){
        this.id = id;
        this.word = word;
    }

    private final String id;
    private final String  word;

    public String getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public static String getGroupByWord2(String word2){

        for (Group group : Group.values()) {
            if (word2.contains( group.getWord())) {
                return group.getId();
            }      
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getId();
    }

}
```

Comment: You're using `word2.contains()` in code 2 and `word2.equalsIgnoreCase()` in code 1. Why would you expect the same results?

Comment: @TedHopp: I forgot to change it but I am still getting not the same result.

Comment: For what `word2` are you not getting the same result?

Answer (score 0):

In the first version, you check if `word2` is either `other company` or `neu company` and return appropriate enum's String representation. But in the second one, you are checking  `word2.contains(group.getWord())` which is going to return true when `group.getWord()` is an empty string and hence you cannot make `word` an empty string for the rest of the enums.

If empty strings are not one of the valid cases (valid `word2`), then just add a condition to check for empty string

```
if (!group.getWord().isEmpty() && word2.contains(group.getWord()))
```

One more difference is that at the end (when no match is found) you return `null` as opposed to an empty string in version 1.

Answer (score 0):

The code is actually working fine, the difference between the two snippets is equalsIgnoreCase() vs contains() and KG2 value is empty string which will match any non-null String value. Test and formatted code with changed contains() to equals() is below:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Group.getGroupByWord2("neu company")); //10460
    System.out.println(Group.getGroupByWord2("other company")); //10462
    System.out.println(Group.getGroupByWord2("non existing")); //null
    System.out.println(Group.getGroupByWord2(" ")); //null
}


public enum Group {

    KG1("10460", "neu company"),
    KG2("10461", ""),
    KG3("10462", "other company"),
    KG4("10463", "");

    Group(String id, String word) {
        this.id = id;
        this.word = word;
    }

    private final String id;
    private final String word;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public static String getGroupByWord2(String word2) {
        for (Group group : Group.values()) {
            if (word2.equalsIgnoreCase(group.getWord())) {
                return group.toString();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getId();
    }

}
```